# Combinatorics - 9 people. 1 on 1 conversations. Everyone must talk to each other. How do I make it so everyone sits out only once?

Tags: combinatorics

There are 9 people in a group. Everyone will talk to all other people in the group. 1-on-1 conversations for 5 minutes. Obviously somebody will be sitting out each round. How do I make it so that every person sits out only once? Tried it with friends and it's difficult. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your keywords are [round robin tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament).

Comment: think of a football(soccer) match where every player has to shake hands with every other player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that works ... But I just got this through trial and error, not through any kind of systematic method:

Round 1: 12,34,56,78

Round 2: 13,24,57,69

Round 3: 14,25,36,89

Round 4: 15,27,38,49

Round 5: 16,28,39,47

Round 6: 17,29,35,68

Round 7: 18,26,45,79

Round 8: 19,37,46,58

Round 9: 23,48,59,67